# How to login into postgres using shell script file?

Tags: linux, puppet

I Need to install Postgres and configure it using puppet.

How to login into psql and execute psql commands using a shell script file?

Comment: Are you not using a Forge module? If not, why?

Comment: Have you tried using expect?

Comment: Check this link out for an example of expect in puppet:  http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/user_and_homedir_recipe_patterns